# Casting interface type in Lazy<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I want something like this:

```
public interface IAnimal
{ }

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public Dog() {}
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public Cat() {}
}

public abstract class TestClassBase
{
    public TestClassBase()
    {
        _lazyAnimal = CreateLazyAnimal();
    }

    private Lazy<IAnimal> _lazyAnimal = null;
    public IAnimal Animal
    {
        get
        { 
            IAnimal animal = null;
            if (_lazyAnimal != null)
                animal = _lazyAnimal.Value;

            return animal;
        }
    }

    // Could be overridden to support other animals
    public virtual Lazy<IAnimal> CreateLazyAnimal()
    {
        // default animal is a dog
        return new Lazy<Dog>(); // this type of casting doesn't work and I don't know a good workground
    }
}
```

I know from tinkering with MEF that it manages to find and store different types, implementing a single interface, into Lazy<T>. Just not sure how to do it myself.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Lazy<Dog>` cannot be converted directly to `Lazy<IAnimal>`, but since `Dog` can be converted to `IAnimal` you can use the `Lazy<IAnimal>` [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642329.aspx) that expects an `IAnimal` (strictly speaking, it takes a Func that returns an `IAnimal`) and provide a `Dog` instead:

```
    public virtual Lazy<IAnimal> CreateLazyAnimal()
    {
        // default animal is a dog
        return new Lazy<IAnimal>(() => new Dog());
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Casting `Lazy<Dog>` to `Lazy<IAnimal>` is not allowed because the types are different (the `Lazy<T>` type inherits just from `object`). In some cases, the casting can make sense - for example casting `IEnuerable<Dog>` to `IEnumerable<IAnimal>`, but the casting isn't safe in all cases.

C# 4.0 adds support for this casting in the safe case. It is called covariance and contravariance. For example, this [article gives a nice overview](http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2010/01/10/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-4.0.aspx).

Unfortunatelly, in C# 4.0 this works only for interfaces and delegates and not for concrete classes (e.g. `Lazy<T>`). You could probably solve the problem by creating interface `ILazy<out T>` and a wrapper for standard `Lazy` type, but it is probably easier to just write conversion from `Lazy<Dog>` to `Lazy<IAnimal>`.

Comment: No need to write a conversion from `Lazy<Dog>` to `Lazy<IAnimal>`; just explicitly use `new Lazy<IAnimal>(() => new Dog())` (instead of having `new Lazy<Dog>()` automatically use the default constructor).

Comment: I'm new to covariance and contravariance, and the concepts seem a bit baffling at first. From what I can tell, wouldn't it have made more sense for Lazy<T> to be defined as Lazy<out T>?

Comment: @mbursill: Yes, it would (in principle). The problem is that you can use `out` modifier only for interfaces and not for classes (it is not quite clear how that would work for classes in general).